# How to print a long string of numbers neatly in python 3.6?

Tags: python

```
>>> text = [ str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
>>> print( " {}".format( ", ".join( str(i) for i in text ) ) )
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
```

Instead of printing a long text string, I would like a neater print out of `text` with 80 characters width for each line, each line is indented with 2 character space and each element to be equally spaced like so:

```
   1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
  61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
  81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
```

Is there a ready python object that I can use to do this? If not, what is the pythonic way of achieving this in python 3.6?

Comment: Check out the `textwrap` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Saelyth pointed out, use `textwrap` to format this, but before that, you need to format each number right justified and take up 2 spaces:

```
import textwrap

text = [str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
one_line = ', '.join('{:>2}'.format(e) for e in text)
# one_line == ' 1,  2,  3, ...'
print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(one_line, width=80)))
```

Output:

```
 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
```

## Update

If you want 2-space indent, the first way is to print each line with the indentation:

```
import textwrap

text = [str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
one_line = ', '.join('{:>2}'.format(e) for e in text)
# one_line == ' 1,  2,  3, ...'
for line in textwrap.wrap(one_line, width=78):
    print('  {}'.format(line))
```

The second way is to use `textwrap.indent`:

```
import textwrap

text = [str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
one_line = ', '.join('{:>2}'.format(e) for e in text)
# one_line == ' 1,  2,  3, ...'
block = '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(one_line, width=78))
print(textwrap.indent(block, '  '))
```

Note that because of the 2-space indentation, I reduced the width from 80 down to 78.

## Update 2

Thanks to Tomerikoo for the suggestion to use `textwrap.fill`, the code is now simpler:

```
import textwrap

text = [str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
one_line = ', '.join('{:>2}'.format(e) for e in text)
# one_line == ' 1,  2,  3, ...'

print(textwrap.fill(one_line,
                    width=80,
                    initial_indent='  ',
                    subsequent_indent='  '))
```

## Update 3

In this updated, I added advice from Tim to reduce the steps further.

```
import textwrap

one_line = ', '.join('{:>2}'.format(e) for e in range(1, 100))
# one_line == ' 1,  2,  3, ...'

print(textwrap.fill(one_line,
                    width=80,
                    initial_indent='  ',
                    subsequent_indent='  '))
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I include an indent of 2 character space for each line?

Comment: @SunBear add kwargs [`initial_indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.initial_indent) and [`subsequent_indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.subsequent_indent). Like so: `textwrap.wrap(one_line, width=80, initial_indent="  ", subsequent_indent="  ")`

Comment: Why not use `fill`? From the docs: *`fill()` is shorthand for `"\n".join(wrap(text, ...))`*

Comment: I did not know about `textwrap.fill` Thank you for the suggestion. That sure simplify things a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I chose your Update 2 solution as answer as it demonstrated how to use textwrap to get what I had asked for. As pointed out by @Tim, for python 3.6, your solution can be further improve by reducing your 1st and 2nd lines to simply `one_line = ", ".join(f"{x:2d}" for x in range(0, 100))`. You might want to improve it further. :)

Comment: python3.6 f-string syntax allows `'{:>2}'.format(e)` to be written as `f'{e:>2}'`. This syntax is shorter and gives faster performance. For a range of 100 elements, f-string syntax gave 2.6% faster performance, while for a range of 10000 elements the f-string syntax gave 10.8% faster performance. Checked using `timeit`. Recommend you amend your Update 3 solution to use f-string syntax.

Comment: I am aware of the f-string, but not use it because not everyone runs on Python version 3.6 which is the minimum version for this feature.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) library:

```
>>> text = [str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
>>> print(textwrap.fill(" {}".format(", ".join(str(i) for i in text)), width=80))
```

The description of `textwrap.fill`:

**`textwrap.fill(text, width=70, **kwargs)`**

> Wraps the single paragraph in text, and returns a single string containing the wrapped paragraph. `fill()` is shorthand for
>
> `"\n".join(wrap(text, ...))`

Basically this function wraps the text to the given width. If you are willing to accept the default width of 70, you can ommit the `width` keyword argument entirely.

Comment: The format expression will not line up columns. Single-digit numbers will be miss-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the other answers are missing the power of the Python formatting mini-language also, as you are using Python 3.6 *f-strings*!

```py
# Format range into a spaced-out string
formatted_range = ", ".join(f"{x:2d}" for x in range(0, 100))

# Split into lines and print
print(textwrap.fill(formatted_range, width=80))
```

`f{x:2d}` will format an integer to take up 2 characters (padded with spaces). More info [here](https://pyformat.info/#number)

Again `textwrap` is used to split across lines, I have used `textwrap.fill` which is a shorthand for `"\n".join(wrap(text, ...))`

Answer (score 1):

```
import textwrap
maximum = 100
text = str([str(i).zfill(len(str(maximum))) for i in range(1, maximum)])[1:-1]
text = textwrap.wrap(text, width=20)
for i in text:
    print(i)
```

This would do the trick, the `textwrap` module makes "lists" of your desired width in case you want to work with those lines. So you just need to feed it some text and get your result.

Also added `zfill` so all numbers are of the same lenght as the maximum number.

If you just need the text, other answers are better.

Answer (score 1):

Using only `format`. We first pack all the elements to one long line while fixing their length to 2. Then just `join`ing the lines with `'\n'` using `cs_in_line` jumps with added 2-spaces:

```py
text = [str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]

one_line = ", ".join("{:>2}".format(num) for num in text)

print("\n".join("  "+one_line[i:i+cs_in_line] for i in range(0, len(one_line), cs_in_line)))
```

And this gives:

```
   1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
  61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 
  81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
```